# Is there any way to hide facebook login button if facebook access is restricted

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I have integrated facebook login button in my site where I got stuck in a scenario where I am trying to hide the facebook login button if I don't have access to facebook. Is there any way to check whether I have access to facebook?

I want to hide this button if I don't have access to facebook.like I in my company there is cyberoam security which don't allow to access facebook & I get warning of cyberoam you don't have access and it distract my site GUI.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going about it the wrong way. In order for you to know that you cannot access a site, you would need to try and access the site. This would inevitably lead to a delay.

You would be better off using ajax to call a routine that checks and if ok displays the login button. The function below will help:

```
function urlExists($url=NULL)  
{  
    if($url == NULL) return false;  
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

I claim no credit for the function, it came from here first, I believe:

http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/05/php-check-if-a-url-exists-with-curl/